# Usage of 'Conveniently left out'

Tags: phrase-usage

At what situation I can use 'Conveniently left out'? Does this have a negative tone(When someone hides something intentionally) or a positive tone(some details were hidden to make something easier to understand)

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to use this particular expression? It sounds to me like a sarcastic way of hinting  that some unpleasant details have intentionally not been mentioned in order to give a more favourable impression.

Comment: Hi @Kate Bunting, I got this phrase from a movie. I just wanted to know what exactly it means.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used for both.  Something can be omitted to skew the result in a negative way like with, say, unemployment statistics.

But in the study of physics you might want to discount some value that is almost negligible, which can be conveniently left out (or left out for convenience).  For example: Light rays emitted from the sun do not travel in parallel lines but this fact can be conveniently left out.  They can be considered parallel for the purposes of calculating distances using the length of shadows cast by the sun's rays.